# Is there a Bluemix API (eg. REST) to order/cancel Bluemix services and containers?

Tags: containers, ibm-cloud

Does Bluemix have an API endpoint that supports ordering and cancelling Bluemix services and containers?   I want to orchestrate the ordering of Bluemix containers and its dependent services without having to do it manually.

Answer (score 2):

For services you can use the Cloud Foundry REST API:

https://apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/222/

For containers there is another REST API:

http://ccsapi-doc.mybluemix.net/

Comment: If you put CF_TRACE=true on your command line or export it you will be able to see the REST URLs the CLI invokes.  For example

`CF_TRACE=true cf ic group list`

Comment: @Alex, thanks for the doc links.  What is the REST API URL?  I've tried using https://containers-api.ng.bluemix.net today, but getting a "Bad Gateway" error.  I can't tell if it's a temporary problem or if I have the wrong endpoint URL.  Thanks

Comment: The URL is correct. Make sure you use "v3" of the API. For example to get all containers you run the following command:  `curl -X GET --header "Accept: application/json" --header "X-Auth-Token: xxxxx " --header "X-Auth-Project-Id: xxxx" "https://containers-api.ng.bluemix.net/v3/containers/json"`

Comment: Also, could you accept the answer as well? To accept you can click on the check mark below the down arrow.